# Ruby Anemone spider adding a tag to each url visited

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, anemone

I have a crawl set up:

```
require 'anemone'

Anemone.crawl("http://www.website.co.uk", :depth_limit => 1) do |anemone|
anemone.on_every_page do |page|
  puts page.url
end
end
```

However I want the spider to use a Google-analytics anti-tracking tag on every URL it visits and not necessarily actually click the links.

I could use the spider once and store all of the URL's and use [WATIR](http://www.watir.com) to run through them adding the tag but I want to avoid this because it is slow and I like the skip_links_like and page depth functions.

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add something to the URL before you load it, correct? You can use [`focus_crawl`](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Anemone/Core.html#M000025) for that.

```
Anemone.crawl("http://www.website.co.uk", :depth_limit => 1) do |anemone|
    anemone.focus_crawl do |page|
        page.links.map do |url|
            # url will be a URI (probably URI::HTTP) so adjust
            # url.query as needed here and then return url from
            # the block.
            url
        end
    end
    anemone.on_every_page do |page|
        puts page.url
    end
end
```

The `focus_crawl` method intended to filter the URL list:

> Specify a block which will select which links to follow on each page. The block should return an Array of URI objects.

but you can use it as a general purpose URL filter as well.

For example, if you wanted to add `atm_source=SiteCon&atm_medium=Mycampaign` to all the links then your `page.links.map` would look something like this:

```
page.links.map do |uri|
    # Grab the query string, break it into components, throw out
    # any existing atm_source or atm_medium components. The to_s
    # does nothing if there is a query string but turns a nil into
    # an empty string to avoid some conditional logic.
    q = uri.query.to_s.split('&').reject { |x| x =~ /^atm_(source|medium)=/ }

    # Add the atm_source and atm_medium that you want.
    q << 'atm_source=SiteCon' << 'atm_medium=Mycampaign'

    # Rebuild the query string 
    uri.query = q.join('&')

    # And return the updated URI from the block
    uri
end
```

If you're `atm_source` or `atm_medium` contain non-URL safe characters then URI-encode them.

Comment: Can you give me an example. If i wanted to add "thisstring" to each website?

Comment: @Benjamin: Add it to what part of the URL? As a CGI parameter?

Comment: an example: "http: //yahoo.co.uk/?atm_source=SiteCon&atm_medium=Mycampaign" Where I want to add 
"?atm_source=SiteCon&atm_medium=Mycampaign" to each url visited.

Comment: @Benjamin: I added a bit of an example for you.